# add javascript to joomla template

Tags: javascript, css, joomla

I create a basic template for joomla.this is my file structure.

```
templateDetails.xml
index.php
css/style.css
js/main.js
```

in index.php i put this line to add javascript and css .

```
<?php

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/style.css');
$doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/main.js', 'text/javascript');

?>
```

css work correctly.but javascript not work .what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `/` from `addScript('/templates/` make it `addScript('templates/` if you are working on localhost it will point to `localhost/` and not to `localhost/yourjoomla/`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `JUri::root()` which defines the root of your Joomla site. You also need to remove the first `/` you have when defining the path for you Javascript file, like so:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->addStyleSheet( JUri::root() . 'templates/' . $this->template . '/css/style.css');
$doc->addScript( JUri::root() . 'templates/' . $this->template . '/js/main.js');
```

You can also use the following if you're using Joomla 2.5 or above:

```
JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::root() . 'templates/' . $this->template . '/css/style.css');
JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'templates/' . $this->template . '/js/main.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this:

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript

There are multiple ways to do it.